# System.InvalidCastException for DataModel Creation using Sqlite as Database

Tags: c#, windows, linq, sqlite

Good Day, I am having this problem of creating data models after installing the entity framework, `SQLite`, `SQLite.linq`, `SQLite.Core` and `SQLite.EF6` from the nugget manager. Below is the screenshot of the error Message

Data Model Creation Error

[image]

Installed Packages From nugget

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have had it figured out, The error code comes from the App.config, So add the following to the entity framework providers in the app.config

```
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.105.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
 <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.105.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
```

You can replace the version number with any of the conflicting versions and its done